# HTTP Status 404 - /SpringMvcDemo/hello

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I am new to springMVC, and my project runs well, but the problem when i send a request with a link, i get **HTTP 404-The requested resource is not available**. error. i have tried code from already asked question but still i have failed to ressolve the error ,here is my code, i  need help

*web.xml*

```
<web-app version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>Hello World Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

*dispatcher-servlet*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

            <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers" />


    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

*controller*

```
package com.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class FirstController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "display.jsp";
    }
}
```

*index.jsp*

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>Hello World!</h2><br>
<a href="hello">greetings</a>

</body>
</html>
```

*display.jsp* 
This is the page i want to render when the link is clicked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>am meant to display</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

*pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sts.practise</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMvcDemo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringMvcDemo Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

           <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMvcDemo</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing **/SpringMvcDemo/src/main/java**
 When i created a new maven webapp, only  */SpitterMvc/src/main/resources* was visible and that were the problem  came from, becouse i wrote my controllers inside the resources folder.
 I resolved the error when i made the other sourcefolder visible, and thats by

*Right clicking the Maven Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path Go to Order and Export tab, you can see the message like '2 build path entries are missing' Now select 'JRE System Library' and 'Maven Dependencies' checkbox Click OK*

And then pasted my controllers code into **/SpringMvcDemo/src/main/java** and now its working